# Does a positive operator define a positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have been playing around with positive operators and I wasn't sure if the following holds or not.

Given a Hilbert space $H$ let $A:H\to H$ be a self-adjoint positive operator: $\langle Ax,x\rangle \ge 0$ for every $x\in H$.

Now, for $x_1,\dots,x_j\in H$, consider the matrix $(\langle A x_j,x_k \rangle)_{jk}=(\langle A^{1/2} x_j,A^{1/2}x_k \rangle)_{jk}$, $ x_j\in H$.

Is this matrix positive semi-definite? What if e.g., $x_j$'s are orthogonal?

I know the diagonal terms are positive and the magnitude wise big but have not been able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix is symmetric positive semidefinite: Let me call the matrix $M$. Let $a\in \mathbb R^j$, define $x:=\sum_i a_ix_i$. Then
$$
a^TMa  = \langle Ax,x\rangle \ge0.
$$